# $(A\times B)\cap (C\times D)=(A\cap C)\times (B\cap D)$: Proof Strategy for Cross Products of Intersected Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that
$$(A\times B)\cap (C\times D)=(A\cap C)\times (B\cap D)?$$

Comment: Use `iff`s. ${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove that by using element chasing. That is, you pick an element from one set, then you unwind the definitions of that set and you rewind them to construct the definition of the other.

For example. Let $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\cap(C\times D)$, then $(x,y)\in A\times B$ and $(x,y)\in C\times D$. Therefore $x\in A$ and $x\in C$, and $y\in B$ and $y\in D$, that is to say $x\in A\cap C$ and $y\in B\cap D$. Therefore $(x,y)\in(A\cap C)\times(B\cap D)$.

This shows that $\subseteq$ holds. If we can establish that $\supseteq$ holds as well, then we have proved the equality. You can do that by the same method.

Another way, is to now that all the translations in the above proof work backwards too, then you can use "if and only if" at each stage and prove both $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ at the same time. My recommendation, however, is to do it one side at a time until you fully grasp the idea behind element chasing.

Comment: What is the opposite of constructivism?

Comment: [Constructivism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(mathematics)) is a perspective in the philosophy of mathematics and does not pertain to this question, Loie.

Comment: @anon: You have to ping people who are not me. :-)

Comment: @anon, Asaf Karagila said "you rewind them to *construct* the definition of the other," and so I'm wondering that since this is a constructivist approach, and some people don't subscribe to this philosophy, what would a non-constructivist find bad about this?

Comment: @anon, take a good, long, hard look at [this](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/c/charleseam403332.html).

Comment: @Loie: The use of the word "construct" need not imply "constructivism".

Comment: Why not? Tell me, why not?

Comment: @Loie: Tell me why yes. Just the fact that the two words have a related meaning in natural language? That's not enough.